# Discord.py API get user data from IP

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I've been looking into the Discord API [source code](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/tree/master/discord) and I was wondering if you could get a user's data. Not just returning their username. There is nothing that I could find in the [API's docks](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

This is the furthest I got:

```
data = await discord.client.Client.fetch_user_profile(discord.client.Client.fetch_user_profile, id)
```

But I keep on getting the error:

```
CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute '_connection'
```

Caused by a what I think may be a function and a variable having the same name. Are there any ways to fix this, or any other methods to get a users data that works. Preferably without having to change the source code. Thanks for any help in advance.

And just in case you need it, here is the entirety of my code:

```
#import libarys
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import os

#setup bot
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='&', owner_id=MyID, case_insensitive=True)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    await bot.change_presence(activity=discord.Activity(type=discord.ActivityType.watching, name='for &help'))
    print(f'\n\nLogged in as: {bot.user} - {bot.user.id}\nVersion: {discord.__version__}\n')

#find user data command
@bot.command()
async def find(ctx, id: int):
    member = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(id)
    data = await discord.client.Client.fetch_user_profile(discord.client.Client.fetch_user_profile, id)
    print(member, data)
    
#connect bot
bot.run(os.environ.get('TOKEN'), bot=True, reconnect=True)
```

EDIT: This code is just a mock up to get a working concept, I don't care to make it more refined yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really bad code, I don't even know how you came up with that code. You're not supposed to refer to the class itself but to the instance, your code fixed

```py
@bot.command()
async def find(ctx, id: int):
    member = await ctx.guild.fetch_member(id)
    data = await bot.fetch_user_profile(id)
    print(member, data)
```

Also note that the `fetch_user_profile` method it's deprecated since version 1.7 and bot accounts cannot use this endpoint

#### Reference:

- [`Client.fetch_user_profile`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_user_profile)

Comment: The fetch_user_profile() is not an available command for bots and where I referred to the class it required a self command. And since I was not executing the command from the same class, it was the fasted and easiest working way (Like I said before I don't want to edit the source code and that class was part of the source code).  And finally, I do understand OOP but this script is just a mock up and I was just attempting to get the concept to work.

Comment: The discord API itself does not allow it, even if you edit the source code of discord.py it's not going to work, there's no way to "bypass" it having a bot account. And sorry, I should have mentioned in the answer that bots cannot use this method.